# C# JMS Application Error when MultiThreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, jms, weblogic

I have a Visual Studio C# JMS Application that sends messages to a WebLogic Queue.  The program is working and works when multi-threading up until the number of threads exceeds 6.  If I run up to 6 threads it works without error but 7 or more threads result in the following exception:

```
WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.TransportException: Server host/port can not be reached - 
An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full 
at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(String host, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras)
at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(IDictionary`2 paramMap) 
WebLogic.Messaging.Transport.TransportException: Server host/port can not be reached - 
An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(String host, Int32 port, TransportUserCfgParameters paras)
at WebLogic.Messaging.Physical.T3TransportFactory.CreateT3Transport(IDictionary`2 paramMap)
```

The queue is never full and messages are consumed faster than being sent.  Each message is less than 1Kb.

Thanks

Comment: Check the version of `weblogic.messaging.dll`? https://community.oracle.com/thread/1133037?tstart=0

Comment: The version is 1.3.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a context every time a message was sent exceeded the number of allowable network connections.  Using a shared context that only creates a single network connection resolved the issue.  See Oracle Documentation, Oracle Fusion Middleware Using the WebLogic JMS Client for Microsoft .NET for Oracle WebLogic Server "Understanding Socket and Threading Behavior".